# How to handle a GUI of an external software from within Java code

Tags: java, user-interface, runtime

I need to run an external application from within my Java code. I can run the application with Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime() and then r.exec(...), however, this brings up the GUI of the application. And I still need enter some settings in some fields and press enter. So:

Is there some way to handle a GUI (filling out fields, pressing "return"..etc) from within Java code?

Thanks in advance for any answers,

Anas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the AWT [Robot class](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html):

*"This class is used to generate native system input events for the purposes of test automation, self-running demos, and other applications where control of the mouse and keyboard is needed."*

Comment: Are you sure that java.awt.Robot can access the other applications as well?

Comment: Ok, thank you for info on this class. I will try this the next chance I get and report the results. I am on widown Vista, and I found that I can simplify the handling the GUI (by changing the default settings to side-step filling out any field), but I would still need to press "enter". I think this might do, we'll see

Comment: The Robot class is designed to emulate mouse clicks, so it definitely can access other systems - it is doing hardware mouse clicks sent to the underlying OS.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks RichieHindle and Vanya for your comments. AWT Robot class does work with an external softwatre (in this instance, I only need to press an enter. It did that, no problem). But further handling seems quite difficult, since every key stroke (entering a username) needs a java line (unless there is someshort cut that I missed). I will try to automata the process more, or find some work around.

Thank you, this was informative.

Anas

Comment: You may want to use something built on top of the java.awt.Robot class - like Abbot and Costello - http://abbot.sourceforge.net/doc/overview.shtml